# insertion sort and printing values

Tags: java, arrays, loops

the prompt says
[image]

so far i've done

```
public class U7_L6_Activity_One {
  public static void sortAndPrintReverse(String [] arr) {
    for (int j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      String temp = arr[j];
      int possibleIndex = j;
      while (possibleIndex > 0 && temp.compareTo(arr[possibleIndex - 1]) < 0) {
        arr[possibleIndex] = arr[possibleIndex - 1];
        possibleIndex--; 
      }
      arr[possibleIndex] = temp;
      for (String str : arr) {
        System.out.print(str + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

but i'm unable to pass three of the test cases and am not sure how to fix the code
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to take care for 2 things:

1. If **size of array is 1** then it should **print the single element** as is.
2. **`temp.compareTo(arr[possibleIndex - 1]) > 0`** should be done since the question asks to be **reverse sorted** (descending order).

```
    public static void sortAndPrintReverse(String [] arr) {
        // size is 1
        if(arr.length==1){
            for (String str : arr) {
                System.out.print(str + " ");
            }
            return;
        }
        
        for (int j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
          String temp = arr[j];
          int possibleIndex = j;
          while (possibleIndex > 0 && temp.compareTo(arr[possibleIndex - 1]) > 0) {
            arr[possibleIndex] = arr[possibleIndex - 1];
            possibleIndex--; 
          }
          arr[possibleIndex] = temp;
          for (String str : arr) {
            System.out.print(str + " ");
          }
          System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just swap the `compareTo` condition from

```java
temp.compareTo(arr[possibleIndex - 1]) < 0
```

to

```java
temp.compareTo(arr[possibleIndex - 1]) > 0
```

Then the output meets the expectations.